# C#: Error when adding key to HttpClient's Default Request Header

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient

I'm getting the following error on my code. The error message is like below:

> Error message returned from the website is: System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource) at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add) at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.AddHeaderToStore(String name, HeaderStoreItemInfo info) at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.Add(String name, String value) at xxxx

I suspect this occur when there are concurrent threads trying to add the same key into the HttpClient's DefaultRequestHeaders. Following is my code:

```
private readonly object httpHeaderLock = new object();

public void Initialize(HttpClient httpClient)
{
    lock (httpHeaderLock)
    {
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        Dictionary<string, string> headers = GetHeaders();

        // Add headers
        foreach (string key in headers.Keys)
        {
            if (!httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Contains(key)) // Only add if does not exist
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(key, headers[key]);
        }
    }

    // Add params
    // Add the parameters to be passed as the endpoint
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int i = 0;
    foreach (string key in ParamsField.Keys)
    {
        if (i == 0)
            sb.Append("?" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(key) + "=" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(ParamsField[key]));
        else
            sb.Append("&" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(key) + "=" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(ParamsField[key]));
        i++;
    }

    Address += sb.ToString();
}

public Dictionary<string, string> GetHeaders()
{
    return HeadersField;
}

public void AddHeaders(string key, string value)
{
    if (!HeadersField.ContainsKey(key))
        HeadersField.Add(key, value);
    else
        HeadersField[key] = value;
}
```

Another class that is going to call the `Initialize` function. This is the child class.

```
public class WSPublish : WSBase
{
    private static string ServiceCode = "SERV_CODE";
    private static HttpClient WSHttpClient;

    public WSPublish()
    {
        WSHttpClient = new HttpClient();
        BaseAddress = "someaddress";
        AddHeaders("key", "somevalue");
        JSSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        WSHttpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseAddress);
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize(WSHttpClient);
    }

    public async Task<WSLog> PostData(string payload)
    {
        try
        {
            Address = BaseAddress;
            Initialize();
            WSLog wsLog = await base.PostData(WSHttpClient, ServerIPAddress, ServiceCode, payload);
            if (wsLog.HTTPStatusCode != Convert.ToInt32(HttpStatusCode.OK))
                throw new Exception("HTTP Status Code is " + wsLog.HTTPStatusCode);
            else
            {
                JToken jToken = JToken.Parse(wsLog.ResponseData);
                // Check the code
                if (jToken.Type == JTokenType.Object)
                {
                    if (jToken["code"].ToString() != "00000") // Some  error
                        throw new Exception("Error posting data, status code is not OK. Error message = " + jToken["msg"].ToString());
                    else
                    {
                        WSResponse<Publish> result = JSSerializer.Deserialize<WSResponse<Publish>>(wsLog.ResponseData);                         
                        return wsLog;
                    }
                }
                else
                    throw new Exception("Error retrieving data. Response data is not an object. Response data = " + wsLog.ResponseData);
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error posting data. Error message = " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Actually I already try to prevent this by having a lock `httpHeaderLock` when adding the key into the DefaultRequestHeaders. I even add the checking `if (!httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Contains(key))` but it also does not seem to work.

Any solution?

Comment: What does GetHeaders() do?

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy, updated the code. It's basically just returning the values in a variable.

Comment: The quick and dirty solution is likely to also lock on `httpClient`.

Comment: How is `Initialize` being called, and how often?

Comment: The first three lines of code in `AddHeaders` could likely be removed.

Comment: @mjwills, added the code to call the Initialize. The frequency depends on the user action, like clicking a button. So if 2 users click the same button, it will call 2 times. Regarding your solution to lock `httpClient`, can you elaborate on that? Is there any side effect?

Comment: Maybe you can aviod duplicate initializations not calling initialize if it is yet called before (using a private variable)... This because you are calling Initialize on every "PostData" call

Comment: why is `WSHttpClient` a `static` field, whereas `httpHeaderLock` is not ?

Comment: `So if 2 users click the same button, it will call 2 times.` The short answer is that is problematic. If two web requests are occurring at the same time, they can't both be fiddling with the httpclient (or its `DefaultRequestHeaders`) since they will (even if it works) inadvertently impact each other. You want different headers - have a different `HttpClient`.

Comment: so do you mean I just remove the `static` from the WSHttpClient to make it have different HttpClient?

Comment: Even without the very serious concurrency issue you have noticed, that the single `HttpClient` instance is used to make different requests where the headers you are specifying as _default_ are different is a clear indication that they have no business being default headers. Set them at the request level. In other words, your design is problematic.